# Submit Announcement for Approval

Tags: list, workflow, content-approval, approval-process, submit

What is the best way to **save an announcement** until it is ready to **submit for approval**. I have to build a News announcement that ANYONE can contribute to our Intranet News, however, the approver (my manager) should only be notified when it is ready for approval, not everytime it is saved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading your message the Approver has already setup alert notifications which makes him receive on changes.

There are couple of possibilities here:

1. Enable content approval, and create a View - where Approval status
   is Pending. Then setup alerts on View.
2. Use a notification workflow as by enabling content Approval workflow on the list
3. Build your own notification workflow with SharePoint Designer to be used on Content Approval
4. Code based solutions - total freedom - and much more complex